# How to delete data using update query? What I mean is I will delete some data but in the database still displayed

Tags: php, mysql

This is a delete query but I want to show the deleted data in the database. Please help me.

```
<?php
    require_once '../students.php';
    $admin_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `students`") or die(mysqli_error());
    $admin_valid = $admin_query->num_rows;
    if($admin_valid == 1){
        echo '<script>alert("Error: Can\'t delete if only one applicant is available")</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location = "student_acc.php"</script>';
    }else{
        $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `students` WHERE `students`.`student_id` = '$_REQUEST[student_id]'") or 
        die(mysqli_error());
        header('location:student_acc.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: So put a flag on your students table like `deleted` then `UPDATE students SET students.deleted = 1 WHERE ...` ? Of course, if you get a GDPR *"right to be forgotten"* request you have to *really* delete the student data.

Comment: How would you show data that is no longer there?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please take a look at [How can I prevent sql injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Your code is heavily prone to SQL injection which means that someone could gain unauthorized access to your SQL database.

Secondly, add a column in your database named `disabled` or similar. Do an update query like the following:

```
UPDATE `students` SET `disabled` = 1 WHERE `student_id` = YOUR_STUDENT_ID
```

On all you future checks for students, just filter out where students have `disabled = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is to make another table where the idea is you will put into **archives** the data you have deleted

It's like a temporary graveyard for your deleted data, though it is still in your database, but at least you will have a copy of your previous records

This is the best practice in companies, we don't literally delete records / data

So to wrap up

**STEP 1**

You delete your data in your main table

**STEP 2**

retrieve that data and insert it in your `archives` table